# Order of join conditions will cause different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
select s.staff_name, s2.staff_name 'supervisor name'
from staff_relation s, staff_Relation s2
where s.staff_no = s2.supervisor
```

and

```
select s.staff_name, s2.staff_name 'supervisor name'
from staff_relation s, staff_Relation s2
where s.supervisor = s2.staff_no
```

Both of them provide different results. Why is this so ?

**UPDATE:** Don't know if it helps,

[Table image link](http://i418.photobucket.com/albums/pp270/ravenoz_bucket/qqq1.png) 
 This image is of a small table I created.

above is the image of the small table I've created.

When I did the 1st command, it shows Anita is Ruth's supervisor. Which is wrong. But when I did the 2nd command, it shows it correctly, Ruth is Anita's supervisor.

Comment: P.S. You use backticks around identifiers, not single quotes. They're not the same thing.

Comment: Please don't close. This is a valuable question, it shows a misunderstanding of the join concept and a is a valuable learning experience for the user and others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't just change the order of join conditions, you changed which table's columns you selected. The results are different because the queries are different.

If you flipped `s` with `s2` in the `SELECT` the same way you flipped it in the `WHERE`, you'd get the same results.

Here's your two queries with nothing but the table aliases changed:

```
select EMPLOYEE.staff_name, SUPERVISOR.staff_name 'supervisor name'
from staff_relation EMPLOYEE, staff_Relation SUPERVISOR
where EMPLOYEE.staff_no = SUPERVISOR.supervisor
```

and

```
select EMPLOYEE.staff_name, SUPERVISOR.staff_name 'supervisor name'
from staff_relation EMPLOYEE, staff_Relation SUPERVISOR
where EMPLOYEE.supervisor = SUPERVISOR.staff_no
```

See why #2 gives you the right result but #1 doesn't now?

Comment: How are the queries different ? Really sorry, I don't understand. I've updated it with more info, hopefully it helps in some way or another.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it more clear to you. Look closely at the `WHERE` clauses. I have not changed anything in the query except the name of the table aliases.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess I finally got it. Will re-digest it again later. Somehow I can't understand this  simple concept properly lol.